# Namespaced class on rails' app folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, activesupport

I have the following folder structure:

```
app
├── assets
├── controllers
├── helpers
├── mailers
├── market_adapters
│   └── german.rb
│...
```

And the file `market_adapters/german.rb` is:

```
module MarketAdapters #(I've also tried naming it singular)
   class German
   end
end
```

When running tests I get the error:

```
/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in
`load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant German, 
expected .../app/market_adapters/german.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

Adding the `market_adapters` folder to the `autoload_paths` seems to have no effect `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/market_adapters"`

If I move the `market_adapters` to the `lib` folder, everything works. But still would like to have it under `app`, any ideas?

By the way, I'm using Rails 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the subfolders in `app` are automatically auto-loaded and added to the load path. Therefore, the folder `market_adapters` is added to the load path, and the file called `german.rb` is expected to define the `German` class.

If you really want to use `market_adapters` as namespace and keep the file in app, you need to store it in the folder `app/market_adapters/market_adapters/german.rb`.

The right place, however, is in lib.

Comment: "The right place, however, is in lib" - I'm going to disagree with you here. This is clearly app-specific functionality. It has no place in lib. Lib is for general-purpose reusable things, like api wrappers, csv generation helpers and whatnot.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this is your interpretation. I personally place in lib all the custom written libraries that have nothing to do with model/controller/views/mailers. Pretty much everything I wrote. And I place them into the application namespace. Feel free to keep them in app, but as you can see, Rails itself seems to prevent it in the architecture.

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev regarding 'the right place'™. But we have to agree that this is the right place at least in Rails' vision :)

Comment: The rails' "prevention" is just a minor detail of how auto-loading works (that is, ignoring name of folder that is directly under `app` as a part of namespace). This is easily solved by putting all your non-MVC but nevertheless app-specific code to `app/custom/market_adapters/german.rb`. Here, you have best of both worlds. :)

Comment: `app/adapters` ?:)

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov: one's app may contain many-many non-mvc types on things: query objects, form objects, service objects, serializers, you name it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, and adapters are one of those non-mvc things :)

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov: yes, what I meant is: don't put adapters in app/adapters/adapters. Put them in app/lib/adapters. And service objects in app/lib/service_objects. This way your "custom" code is nicely contained and there are no silly looking double folder names.

Comment: You can use the "Rails way" and add the folder as a class name suffix like in controllers, e.g UsersController. Then you'll have app/market_adapters/german_market_adapter.rb. Is not what you tried, but it's another option.